# Crear un proyecto que contenga @repository, @service y @controller

Tags: spring-boot

No se como crear un proyecto nuevo con spring initializr que contenga @repository, @service, y @controller, para que exista la dependencia de controller es necesario 
marcar la siguiente casilla, aca un screenshot:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero para las otras que se debe marcar?, o como los adiciono manualmente

segun el comentario de @luiggiMendoza, los otros 2 son del core, pero cuales marco?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Las otras son parte de Spring Core. No deberías agregar nada, las anotaciones ya existen en el proyecto.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza edite mi pregunta, existen por defecto las dependencias?

Comment: amigo ve al chat

Comment: ya puedes hablar, recarga la pagina del chat

Comment: @CriticalGhost no puedo hablar, no aparece el textarea

Comment: recarga la pagina men

Comment: F5 men, o salte y vuelve a entrar y listo

Comment: @deluf sí. Las dependencias van por defecto. Está en la parte más importante de Spring. Es decir, si no tienes esas dependencias, no estás usando Spring ;)

Comment: como marco respuesta correcta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las anotaciones que mencionas se encuentran dentro del paquete `org.springframework.stereotype` que se encuentra en la librería Spring Context. Esta librería es parte del corazón de Spring. Es decir, si no agregas esta librería, simplemente no puedes trabajar con Spring.

En resumen, no necesitas marcar un check específico para decir que deban incluirse estas librerías. Ya están agregadas por defecto.